# Associate multiple values to one key in a dictionary Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

So I am working on this text mining project. I am trying to open all files, grab information of organizations and abstracts, split words in abstracts, and then find out how many files every word shows.
My questions is about the last step: how many files does one word show? To answer this question, I am making a dictionary wordFrequency to count that. I am trying to tell the dictionary: if a word does not show in the dictionary, capture the word and file number attached to it; if a word shows in dictionary, but the file number is different from any existing ones, append the file number behind it. If both the word and its file number is already in the dictionary, ignore it. Below is my code.

```
capturedfiles = []
capturedabstracts = []
wordFrequency = {}
wordlist=open('test.txt','w')
worddict=open('test3.txt','w')
for filepath in matches[0:5]:
    with open (filepath,'rt') as mytext:
    mytext=mytext.read()
    #print mytext

    # code to capture file organizations.
    grabFile=re.findall(r'File\s+\:\s+(\w\d{7})',mytext)
    if len(grabFile) == 0:
        matchFile= "N/A"
    else:
        matchFile = grabFile[0]
    capturedfiles.append(matchFile)

    # code to capture file abstracts
    grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s\:\s\d{7}\s(\w.+)',mytext)
    if len(grabAbs) == 0:
        matchAbs= "N/A"
    else:
        matchAbs = grabAbs
    capturedabstracts.append(matchAbs)

    # arrange words in format.
    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0
    lines = matchAbs[0].split('. ')
    for line in lines:
        lineCount +=1
        for word in line.split(' '):
            wordCount +=1
            wordlist.write(matchFile + '|' + str(lineCount) + '|' + str(wordCount) + '|' + word + '\n')

            if word not in wordFrequency:
                wordFrequency[word]=[matchFile]
            else:
                if matchFile not in wordFrequency[word]:
                        wordFrequency[word].append(matchFile)
                worddict.write(word + '|' + str(matchFile) + '\n')


wordlist.close()
worddict.close()
```

What I am getting now is every word gets printed out with its matching file number. If a word shows up twice in the whole text, it will prints out twice separately. Below is an example of how it looks like:

variation|a9500006
are|a9500006
are|a9500007

I want it to look like:

variation|a9500006
are|a9500006, a9500007

Comment: The behavior that you desire is exactly how `dict` objects work, the problem here is with the way you print text. If you print just the dict, you should see keys paired with multiple values.

Comment: When I tried `print wordFrequency`, it repeatedly printed out the results. When I wrote it in another file, every single word is listed. If a word shows up multiple times in one file or multiple files, they are all separately listed.

Comment: put `print wordFrequency` outside of any loops and at the bottom of your code.

Comment: I just tried to put `print` statement, it will loop print the the same result. Cannot move it any further outside, otherwise there would be an error message "unexpected indentatio". Also, I wanted to write this into a file, any suggestions on the code? Thanks.

Comment: "Cannot move it any further outside, otherwise there would be an error message "unexpected indentatio"." have you tried unindenting it?

Comment: I did. It wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to `worddict` every time in a loop, write the whole `wordFrequency` dictionary after building it. Like so:

```
#assuming wordFrequency is a correctly built dictionary
for key, value in wordFrequency.items():
    #key is a word, value is a list
    worddict.write(key + '|')
    for word in value:
        #write each word in value
        worddict.write(word)
        #if it's not the last word, write a comma
        if word != value[-1]:
            worddict.write(', ')
    #no more words, end line
    worddict.write('\n')
```

PS: ***Never, ever, EVER mix tabs and spaces! Especially in python!***

Comment: @Q-ximi Please explain why, your question is quite confusing. And looking at the comments, it seems I'm not the only one who thinks so.

Comment: I nested this piece of code under 'wordFrequency[word]=[matchFile]', it gave me something really weird. The printed out looks like this`|N/Aa9500003
|a9500006less|a9500006fabricated|a9500006tradeoffs|a9500006identify|a9500006(GOALI)|a9500006nominally|a9500006rapid|a9500006improvement|a9500006to|a9500006other|a9500006fuel|a9500006openings|a9500006good|a9500006crash|a9500006very|a9500006automotive|a9500006Industry|a9500006possibly|a9500006deviaitons|a9500006***`

Comment: You should place the code at the very end (but before closing, obviously)

Comment: I put it where I am trying in the post. Could you please edit my post so that I know if my indentation is right? Thanks.

Comment: @Q-ximi just indent it the way I did...seriously, this is basic python knowledge... and don't mix tabs and spaces!

Comment: Maybe. I am just learning it by myself. Not taking any class. That is probably why I am not aware of some basics. But if you review your original reply, that is how you put it. Also, the revised code does not work either. The result looks like this: `a|Wang|for|Grant|This|award|N|Opportunity|a9500006`

Comment: @Q-ximi sorry but that just can't be the result of my code. It looks like the values were empty, but it's impossible since you add a key along with its value. I edited and commented my code